# Obtener datos del código de barras

Tags: asp.net-core, código-de-barras

Recientemente comencé un proyecto en el cual deseamos incluir códigos de barras de los productos a registrar, mi duda es si ¿Es posible obtener mas que solo el código de barras? es decir que cuando escanee el código de  X producto pueda obtener también su marca, contenido neto, el tipo de presentación cosas de ese estilo sin necesidad de capturarlo uno por uno.

El objetivo es crear una especie de punto de venta pero me gustaría evitar empezar de 0 con la base de datos y de alguna manera  poder pre cargar todos estos datos para evitarle al usuario crear su inventario de manera manual.

Comment: Podría pedir a los proveedores datos con los cuales empezar a poblar tu db

Comment: los codigos de barras son simplemente codigos numericos, cada supermercado o proveedor usa ese ID para poder buscarlo en su DB